# Multi threading-Odd Even Number

Tags: java, multithreading

Printing odd/even num by 2 diss threads alternatively..The program is not ending. The EVEN thread is in wait state. Tried adding 'notifyAll()' outside while loop. also if I set the evenFlag/oddFlag outside while loop, the thread names change back to Thread1 and Thread2, not sure why..

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public class MultiThreading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Runnable r = new PrintNum();
        Thread t0 = new Thread(r, "ZERO");
        Thread todd = new Thread(r, "Thread1");
        Thread teven = new Thread(r, "Thread2");
        t0.start();
        todd.start();
        teven.start();
    }

    public static class PrintNum implements Runnable {
        boolean zeroFlag = true;
        boolean evenFlag = false;
        boolean oddFlag = false;
        int count = 0;
        int limit = 100;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (count <= limit) {
                    if (zeroFlag) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + count);
                        count++;
                        zeroFlag = false;
                        oddFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (evenFlag) {
                        if (count == 2)
                            Thread.currentThread().setName("EVEN");
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + count);
                        count++;
                        evenFlag = false;
                        oddFlag = true;
                        notify();
                        while (!evenFlag) {
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (oddFlag) {
                        if (count == 1)
                            Thread.currentThread().setName("ODD");
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + count);
                        count++;
                        evenFlag = true;
                        oddFlag = false;
                        notify();
                        while (!oddFlag) {
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine here, and I don't see what could cause the problem. Are you sure you're executing the code you posted?

Comment: Those boolean flags and the `count` variable should definitely all be declared `volatile`.

Comment: @JBNizet That's the thing about multithreading bugs. They don't happen every time, or even the same way every time. It'll depend on the machine, luck or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t want to be rude, and it is ok to ask questions while learning, but it looks like you are trying to get your homework done by someone on Stackoverflow…

Just add following lines in the run method after your while block, one of your threads remains in waiting state otherwise.

```
evenFlag = true;
oddFlag = true;
notify();
```

Try to add System.out.println/debug lines to see what happens before posting a question next time. Also, try to use Java concurrency APIs instead of manually synchronizing threads, AtomicInteger will do what you are trying to do here in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution,

```
public class ThreadPrintingOddEven {

volatile int status = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPrintingOddEven threadNumberPrinting = new ThreadPrintingOddEven();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread_Odd(threadNumberPrinting), "Thread1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread_Even(threadNumberPrinting), "Thread2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}}

class MyThread_Odd implements Runnable {
private ThreadPrintingOddEven threadNumberPrinting;
ThreadLocal<Integer> localCoutn = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();

public MyThread_Odd(ThreadPrintingOddEven threadNumberPrinting) {
    this.threadNumberPrinting = threadNumberPrinting;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (threadNumberPrinting) {
        localCoutn.set(1);
        while (threadNumberPrinting.status < 100) {

            // while (((threadNumberPrinting.status % 2) == 0 &&
            // (threadNumberPrinting.status % 2) == 0))
            while (!(threadNumberPrinting.status == localCoutn.get())) {
                try {
                    threadNumberPrinting.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is Printing :" + threadNumberPrinting.status);
            threadNumberPrinting.status = threadNumberPrinting.status + 1;
            int tempLocal = localCoutn.get();
            tempLocal = tempLocal + 2;
            localCoutn.set(tempLocal);

            threadNumberPrinting.notifyAll();

        }

    }

}}

class MyThread_Even implements Runnable {
private ThreadPrintingOddEven threadNumberPrinting;
ThreadLocal<Integer> localCoutn = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();

public MyThread_Even(ThreadPrintingOddEven threadNumberPrinting) {
    this.threadNumberPrinting = threadNumberPrinting;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (threadNumberPrinting) {
        localCoutn.set(2);
        while (threadNumberPrinting.status < 100) {
            // while((threadNumberPrinting.status%2)==1){
            while (!(threadNumberPrinting.status == localCoutn.get())) {
                try {
                    threadNumberPrinting.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is Printing :" + threadNumberPrinting.status);
            threadNumberPrinting.status = threadNumberPrinting.status + 1;
            int tempLocal = localCoutn.get();
            tempLocal = tempLocal + 2;
            localCoutn.set(tempLocal);

            threadNumberPrinting.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}}
```